# registration form not not showing validation error

Tags: php

I am having issues getting the error to appear when a user is entering a user name that is already taken.

In the code below the database is updated when successful entry is made. However, when an entry is made with a duplicate user name, the entry is placed in the database and no error message is shown. I have looked on the net and tried a few methods and this what I have so far. Thank you for taking a look :)

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con = mysqli_connect('172.16.254.111', "user", "password", "database"); //(connection location , username to sql, password to sql, name of db)
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
} //sql syntax below, first line is collumn titles on the db and second line is values from the html document
//$_post is a form of sending information in php
{
    $username   = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
    $password   = md5(strip_tags($_POST['pass']));
    $password2  = md5(strip_tags($_POST['pass2']));
    $fullname   = strip_tags($_POST['fullname']);
    $email      = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
    $department = strip_tags($_POST['department']);
    if ($password != $password2) //password doestn equal same as password 2 then the message below is displayed (working)
        {
        echo "<H2>password doesn't match</H2>";
    }
    $usercheck  = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username=$username";
    $usercheck2 = mysql_query($usercheck);
    if (mysql_fetch_assoc($usercheck2)) {
        echo "<H2>This username already exists, please pick another</H2>";
    } else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO Users(username, password, password2, email, fullname, department) 
                                                                                VALUES('$username','$password','$password2','$email','$fullname','$department')";
        if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
            die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
        }
        echo "<H2>Registration was successful, please use the access console above</H2>";
    }
}
?>
```

Excuse any comments in the code; I am a beginner at PHP and coding in general.

Comment: You need to put some debugging code in - you're assuming that all your queries work. Also, you're using mysql_* functions in some places, and mysqli_ functions in others. Stick with one (and that one should be mysqli). Finally, your password check will print up a message if the passwords don't match; but it doesn't actually stop the account then being created.

Comment: I would suggest that you didn't display a specific error saying the username already exists as you are then telling someone they have guessed a valid username and just made it easier for them to get in.

Comment: You are **wide open** to SQL injection attacks and **you will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Use prepared/parameterized queries to avoid this problem entirely.

Comment: first of all, fix your indentation! If i need to scroll right, you indented too much your line

Comment: It looks like there some parts of your code are missing. You may want to take a look at [PDO][1] mysqli is not that bad but PDO would be the right way to do this. If you're a beginner and you'd like to improve your skills, Codecademy's PHP track is a great place to start http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/php


  [1]: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php "PDO"

Comment: Considering the OP said they are new to coding, I would imagine they have no idea what SQL injection is. Might be nice to direct them rather than tell them they'll be hacked! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection Also, I think it is unreasonable to let the user know they can't use that name. You can view the usernames of everyone on MOST social media/networking websites. Back to the OP, definitely look at using mysqli_ functions, rather than mixing mysqli and mysql. Also, it is good practice to only select what you NEED in a query, rather than `Select *` in every query.

Comment: i looked at the sql injecton risk page on this forum, as i am learning and this site is not live yet i just need to get the basics working. didnt know i was using 2 syntaxes for sqli will have to look up mysqli.

Comment: Can be a little daunting, but here is mysqli_ http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php You also might want to look into breaking your code into functions (or even just one), so that you can get rid of the nested if/else that makes your code indent to timbucktoo. If it is in a function you can keep the tests to one level of if/else and just return if an error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing some quotes. Try this:

```
$usercheck = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username = '$username'";
// ----------------------------------was missing---^---------^
$usercheck2 = mysql_query($usercheck);
if (mysql_num_rows($usercheck2)) {
    echo 'user exists';
}
```

Also, you shouldn't be using the `mysql_*` functions. Look into using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: adding the '$username' did not enable the message to appear. I might just have to start the code again with fresh eyes. Thank you all for all your comments. I will look into sqli and pdo.

Comment: $sql="INSERT INTO Users(username, password, password2, email, fullname, department) 
                     VALUES('$username','$password','$password2','$email','$fullname','$department')";
                   if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
                   {
                   echo "<H2>The Username already exists please try another</H2>";
                   }
                  
                  else{
                   echo "<H2>Registration was successful, please use the access console above</H2>"; 
                   }

Answer (score 0):

Change $usercheck = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username=$username";
for this $usercheck = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username='$username'"; And tell me if it works.

Comment: it is the same using `''` or without if you use a `variable`